# ADC way faster than microcontroller

Tags: downsampling

I am getting into signal processing, and am working on a project.

My analog-to-digital converter has a sample rate of 10 kHz, whereas my microcontroller can only handle up to 3 kHz.

- What does that mean?
- Will my Microcontroller get overspammed and start burning?
- do i need downsampling after adc? what would the benefits be of doing so?

My input signal is a 4 kHz sensor signal.

Comment: "my micrcocontroller can only handle up to 3 kHz" says *who*? That sounds plain wrong. And "overspammed" is definitely not a term that anyone understands. I can assure you that it'll be very hard to ignite anything with an ADC.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Do you need to sample at 10 kHz? Usually ADCs have a maximum sampling rate but can be run at lower rates.

2 - As we don't know the protocol you use (is the ADC an SPI master or slave? Or I2C?) we cannot know what would happen. Assuming you have a microcontroller interrupt at each sample period, the worst that could happen is that your microcontroller would always be interrupted and thus unable to perform its task. This would be a problem.

3 - Downsampling could be useful but I fail to see how you would do it. Does your ADC have a downsampling option? Does your microcontroller have some kind of "co-processor" to perform such tasks?